# I am trying to run javascript string replace method on a liquid code saved as string inside a varible, but its not working

Tags: javascript, string, search, replace, liquid

I wanted to create an email template generator for myself. The idea is pretty simple. The user would paste a liquid email template inside a text area. Then I am saving that text area value inside a variable.

When the user clicks on the "Inject" button I am running javaScript string.replace() method to replace some portion of that liquid with another code which is also pre-saved as a string inside another variable.

But when I run the code it does not replace the liquid code. It does not show any error either.

Here is the js I have written to achieve the functionality.

```
  // This function runs when user clicks the inject button
  const injectCode = () => {
    if (code.value !== "") {
      state.userInput = code.value;
      let replaced = state.userInput.replace(
        state.find,
        state.replace
      );
      code.value = replaced;
    } else {
      console.log("please paste your email template");
    }
  };
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7f6bgda/5/) link for full code.

Can anyone help me to find out what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using Regex, The problem was white space-related. Normal replace search using plain string did not work, but after I replace that using regex it worked nicely.